# wp7 Webbrowser : We're having trouble displaying this page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, browser

how to catch the error like "We're having trouble displaying this page." of the webbrowser control ?

Answer (score 2):

The most you can do is handle `NavigationFailed`:

```
browser.NavigationFailed += new System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventHandler(browser_NavigationFailed);

void browser_NavigationFailed(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Exception);
}
```